# Python group by - change null values if ID's are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

| ID | value | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID-1 | value | 50 |
| ID-2 | N/A | 20 |
| ID-2 | value | 10 |
| ID-1 | N/A | 40 |
| ID-3 | N/A | 30 |
| ID-4 | N/A | 100 |
| ID-2 | value | 10 |

In my example i have a dataframe with three columns one with ID's and the other with values and cost, all the values are the same, however only some ID's will have that value, If an ID in the list is given that value i would like all the other items with the same ID to be given the value, then grouped together by cost after and if theres still N/A in the value they are just removed. And the order could be random.

The end result for the example above would look like this:

| ID | value | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID-1 | value | 50 |
| ID-2 | value | 20 |
| ID-2 | value | 10 |
| ID-1 | value | 40 |
| ID-3 | N/A | 30 |
| ID-4 | N/A | 100 |
| ID-2 | value | 10 |

Then after some sort of grouping it would look like this finally:

| ID | value | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID-1 | value | 90 |
| ID-2 | value | 40 |

---

I know the below would potentially work for the grouping part but the first part not too sure:

```py
df = df.groupby(["ID", "value"], as_index=False).agg({'Cost': 'sum'})
```

Comment: `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({'value': 'first', 'Cost': 'sum'}).dropna()`

Answer (score 1):

You can first [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)
         .agg({'value': 'first', 'Cost': 'sum'})
         .dropna(subset='value')
      )
```

Output:

```
     ID  value  Cost
0  ID-1  value    90
1  ID-2  value    40
```

For the intermediate (which is not needed if you want the last step only), you can simply [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with the [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df.fillna(df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
     ID  value  Cost
0  ID-1  value    50
1  ID-2  value    20
2  ID-2  value    10
3  ID-1  value    40
4  ID-3   None    30
5  ID-4   None   100
6  ID-2  value    10
```